# Check if an object is an instance of a given class or of a subclass of it

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there an easy way to do this in Smalltalk? I'm 80% sure that there is some method but can't find it anywhere.

I know that I can use

```
(instance class = SomeClass) ifTrue:
```

And I know that I can use `superclass` etc... but I hope that there is something built in :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To test whether anObject is instance of aClass:

```
(anObject isMemberOf: aClass)
```

To test whether it is an instance of aClass or one of it subclasses:

```
(anObject isKindOf: aClass)
```

Answer (score 6):

You are right, to check for exact class you use (using identity instead):

> instance class == SomeClass ifTrue: []

Usefull is also `isKindOf:` which tests if instance is a class or subclass of given class:

> (instance isKindOf: SomeClass) ifTrue: []

Nicest and most elegant is to write a testing method in superclass and peer classes, then use it like:

> instance isSomeClass ifTrue: []

Comment: Nicest and most elegant is to not ask, tell, e.g.:  
instead of:  
    object isSomething ifTrue: [ do something ]  
use:  
    object doSomething

Comment: I agree with Igor.  Moreover, "nicest and most elegant" is in the eye of the beholder.  What isInteger and friends do is definitely *faster* as they are a single message send that immediately returns true/false versus isKindOf: which has to loop up the class hierarchy.  The downside for some people is that you have to add a isSomeClass method to Object which returns false.